# Avoid restarting julia REPL everytime you make an ammendment to a function

Tags: julia

I am working on a julia code where I have several files and call functions from these files to a main function called `run.jl`. Every time I make changes to any one of these files I need to restart the julia REPL which is a bit annoying. Anyway to work around this.
For example

```
# --------------------------------- run.jl
include("agent_types.jl")
include("resc_funcs.jl")

using .AgentTypes: Cas, Resc
using .RescFuncs: update_rescuers_at_pma!, travel_to_loc

# ... some code

for i = 1:500
   update_rescuers_at_pma!(model)
   travel_to_loc(model)
end

# ------------------------------ resc_funcs.jl
function travel_to_loc(model)
    println(get_resc_by_prop(model, :on_way_to_iz))
    for resc_id in get_resc_by_prop(model,:on_way_to_iz)
        push!(model[resc_id].dist_traject, model[resc_id].dist_to_agent) #This is just for checking purposes
        model[resc_id].dist_to_agent -= model.dist_per_step 
        push!(model[resc_id].loc_traject, "on_way_to_iz")
    end
    #If we add new print statement here and execute run.jl it wont print
    println(model[resc_id].loc_traject) #new amendment to code
end
```

But now when I go and update `travel_to_loc` function for example. I need to restart the julia repl before those changes are reflected. I am wondering if there is a way after you save the file (resc_funcs.jl in this case) those amendments are reflected when you execute `run.jl`.

Comment: You don't need to restart the REPL, just rerun the function definition and the REPL will pick it up. But for a better workflow that makes it easier to pick up changes in files, use Revise.jl. It's one of the core packages for Julia development.

Comment: Revise.jl has a very useful function `includet()` notice the `t`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest workflow could be the following:

1. Select some folder to be your current working folder in Julia (eg. by using `cd()` command from Julia)
2. Create sample file `MyMod.jl`

   ```
   module MyMod

   export f1
   function f1(x)
       x+1
   end
   end
   ```
3. Add the current folder to `LOAD_PATH` and load `Revise.jl`

   ```
   push!(LOAD_PATH, ".")
   using Revise
   ```
4. Load the module and test it:

   ```
   julia> using MyMod
   [ Info: Precompiling MyMod [top-level]

   julia> f1(3)
   4
   ```
5. Try to edit the file eg. change `x+1` to `x+3`
6. Run again

   ```
   julia> f1(3)
   6
   ```

Notes:

- you will still need to restart REPL when your data structures change (you modify a definition of a `struct` object)
- you could generate a full module package using `Pkg.generate` but I wanted to make things simplified.